# SQL - calculating overlap of products bought together by customers

Tags: sql

I am using SQL. My database looks like this:

| Customer_ID | Product_ID | Number of purchased Product_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | x | 1 |
| 1 | y | 6 |
| 2 | x | 15 |
| 2 | z | 1 |
| 3 | y | 1 |
| 3 | z | 1 |
| 3 | x | 5 |
| 4 | x | 2 |
| 4 | y | 1 |

I want to find how often the same product combination is bought by the customers.
**To Calculate Times_Bought_Together_%:** count of Product_ID_1 in the first column is divided by the total count of customers of both.
This means that the Number of purchased Product_ID has to be ignored as the calculation is made on the #customer_ID level and not #product_ID level

In this example, combination xy has been bought by 3 out of 4 (Customer_ID = 1,2,3,4), combination zx  by 1 out of 2 (Customer_ID = 2,3), combination yz 1 out of 3 (Customer_ID = 1,3,4)

the result should show something like this:

| Product_ID_1 | Bought_With_Product_ID_2 | Times_Bought_Together_in_% |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | y | 75% |
| z | x | 50% |
| y | z | 33% |

I used a self-join and window functions to calculate this:

```
   select a.product_id, b.product_id,
          count(*) as times_bought_together,
          count(*) * 1.0 / cnt as ratio
    
    from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by product_id) as cnt
              from t
             ) a join
             t b
             on b.customer_id = a.customer_id and
                b.product_id != a.product_id 
    group by a.product_id, b.product_id, a.cnt;
```

however instead of counting each row, the count( * ) function counts the total Number of purchased product_ID for each row which I am not interested in. How could I change the count( * ) in my ratio function to calculate what I am looking for?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Why a set of values `{y; z}` is equal 33%? Note: these products have been bought only by one of four customers (Customer_Id =3)? This should be 25%. Am i right?

Comment: the logic is: Y is bought by 3 customers (Customer_ID = 1,3,4), and only 1 of these customers has bought YZ (Customer_ID = 3). Therefore 1/3 = 33%

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want something in the `select` list, then just don't include it:

```
select a.product_id, b.product_id,
       CAST(count(*) * 1.0 / cnt AS DECIMAL(10,2)) as ratio
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by product_id) as cnt
      from t
     ) a join
     t b
     on b.customer_id = a.customer_id and
        b.product_id <> a.product_id and 
        a.product_id < b.product_id
group by a.product_id, b.product_id, a.cnt;
```

Note:  Your results suggest that you actually want `a.product_id < b.product_id`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added 'count( * ) as times_bought_together' to show that the count( * ) in my ratio function does not give the right calculation. Instead of counting each row, it counts each Number of purchased Product_ID for each row. How could I change the count(*) function to calculate what I am looking for?

Comment: @Es-Dot . . . The answer looks correct for the data you have provided.  Can you set up a db<>fiddle?

Comment: Well... Seems that Es-Dot is wrong with his own calculations. Please, take a look at my comment to the question.